# Swift - Populating array from JSONElemetns

Tags: iphone, arrays, swift

I am using the `JSONSerializer` to access data from a SQL database. I am managing to get the data to read in with no problems and managing to get each entry and create an temporary object with each entry. I added each object to an array. However, when I check the length of the array outside this method, it returns 0, where it should return 5. When checking the length of the array throughout the method, it returns 5. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
func getJson() {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {

                do{

                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    for index in 0..<myJson.count {

                    if let entry = myJson[index] as? NSDictionary{
                        let name = entry["Name"] as! String
                       let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(entry["Longitude"] as! String)
                        let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(entry["Latitude"] as! String)

                        let quiet = Int(entry["Quiet"] as! String)
                        let moderate = Int(entry["Moderate"] as! String)

                        let busy = Int(entry["Busy"] as! String)
                        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                        let tempPark = CarPark(name: name, latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!, quiet: quiet!, moderate: moderate!, busy: busy!, coordinate: coordinate)

                        self.carParks.append(tempPark)
                        print("amount of parks: \(self.carParks.count)")
                        print("name of parks in array: \((self.carParks[index]))")
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        }
}
    print("amount of parks: \(self.carParks.count)")
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Because it's asynchrone. Check when is done the log `print("amount of parks: \(self.carParks.count)")` and when is done `print("name of parks in array: \((self.carParks[index]))")
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your function works asynchronously, that's why when you try to count the elements it returns 0, because there are no elements yet. I would use a completion handler to retrieve the array once it is completed.

```
func getJson(completion: @escaping (Array<ObjectType>) -> Void) {
.
.
.
.
completion(localCarParks)
.
.
.
.
}
```

In the function above you define the completion handler that will handle the answer. Inside the function, once you finish loading the elements, you call the handler with the localCarPerks array.

And to call the getJson function, it would be something like this:

```
self.getJson { (array) in
    // Here you do what you need with the array
}
```